# JS Create a svg file of custom diagram

Tags: javascript, svg, diagram

I wrote an app a while ago in Java using the graphics library java fx.  The app generates diagrams like the following examples:
[image: Chart 1]

[image: Chart 2]

I want to port this app to run on the web.  I was thinking of using Javascript to draw an svg file on the browser.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question...

Comment: @jcaron ahh that is a pretty broad question.  I guess if I could narrow it down more I would ask: what is the best way for drawing basic lines on a blank screen?  Does that help?